# how to update some attribute on update in rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Task` model with attributes `start_date`, `end_date` and `previous_end_date`.

now on `task` update#action i want to take end_date date value and save it to previous_end_date or update it if existing. and then update end_date value with new end_date value on update action.

what i tried:-

task.rb

```
  before_update :add_previous_end_date
  def add_previous_end_date
    previous_end_date = start_date
    previous_end_date.save
  end
```

Comment: What output does this code give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of active model dirty methods like end_date_was, end_date_changed?

```
# app/models/task.rb

before_update :add_previous_end_date

def add_previous_end_date
  if end_date_changed?
    self.previous_end_date = end_date_was
  end
end
```

Don't use save in callbacks

Please refer the link for more details on this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: on update it not doing anything to attribute ```previous_end_date```

Comment: Only when end_date is modified previous_end_date will change

Comment: yes on end_date change ```previous_end_date``` shows nil

Comment: I believe the requirement is update previous_end_date with end_date if end_date is changed. So when a record does not have end_date initially and if you update the end_date then previous_end_date will be nil only.

Comment: hey you just updated your answer by adding ```self```

Answer (score 0):

just found working solution of myself
posting solution here:-

```
before_update :add_previous_end_date

def add_previous_end_date
  if end_date_changed?
    self.previous_end_date = end_date_was
  end
end
```